# Spring boot actuator auditevents with custom ReactiveAuthenticationManager

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I have setup my own `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`

```
public class CustomReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager
```

and then in SecurityWebFilterChain:

```
.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
```

However after this setup im not getting anything in the actuator `auditevents` endpoint:

```
{"events":[]}
```

What do I need to change to have audit events even if I use a custom `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with your custom `AuthenticationManager`. It is a limitation of Spring Security. At the time of writing, events are not published when using reactive Spring Security. An enhancement that will remove the limitation is being tracked in [this Spring Security issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4961).